# MQ : The maximum number of instances of channel was reached

Tags: java, spring, jms, ibm-mq

I have a Java client that connects to MQ, and the queue manager complains that `The maximum number of instances, 50, of channel 'CHAN' was reached`.

Where and how can I find out the number of instances created by my Java client, in client code or properties ?

Comment: Is this a JMS or non-JMS Java application?  Are you using thread pooling in the JMS application?  If so, what value did you use for the pool or is it unlimited?  i.e. is it 60, 75, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You application will cause a new channel connection every time it connects to the queue manager (unless it shares connections - more later). If you repeatedly connect without disconnecting you could have the problem you describe.

You can see all the channel connections on the queue manager by using the following MQSC command (issued through the `runmqsc` tool:-

```
DISPLAY CHSTATUS(CHAN)
```

In your case it would seem that the SVRCONN channel has been configured to only allow 50 connections before emitting the error you have seen. This is configured on an attribute of the SVRCONN channel called MAXINSTC (or possibly MAXINST).

If your SVRCONN channel is configured with SHARECNV set to 10 you may be able to share 10 connections over a single instance of the SVRCONN channel before a second SVRCONN instance is created. This could mean that you are actually making 500 connections before you hit the limit of 50. You can see the count of connections used on a particular instance of the SVRCONN channel by extending the command above to be:-

```
DISPLAY CHSTATUS(CHAN) CURSHCNV MAXSHCNV
```

Review your Java application code to see whether you are repeatedly making connections when you don't need to, and/or not disconnecting. Post your code in the question for further help.